# how do I refactor this to make single function calls?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been using this for a while updating mysql as needed.  However I'm not too sure on the syntax..and need to migrate the sql to an array.

Particulary the line

```
database::query("CREATE TABLE $name($query)");
```

Does this translate to

```
CREATE TABLE bookmark(name VARCHAR(64), url VARCHAR(256), tag VARCHAR(256), id INT)
```

This is my ...guess.  Is this correct?

```
class table extends database
{
    private function create($name, $query)
    {
        database::query("CREATE TABLE $name($query)");
    }

    public function make($type)
    {
        switch ($type) 
        {
            case "credentials":
                self::create('credentials', 'id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, flname VARCHAR(60), email VARCHAR(32), pass VARCHAR(40), PRIMARY KEY(id)');
                break;
            case "booomark":
                self::create('boomark', 'name VARCHAR(64), url VARCHAR(256), tag VARCHAR(256), id INT');
                break;
            case "tweet":
                self::create('tweet', 'time INT, fname VARCHAR(32), message VARCHAR(128), email VARCHAR(64)');
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception('Invalid Table Type');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't include the function definition that you're asking about. The static function query is getting called on the database class, not the table class.

Comment: Note: `self` is meant to be used for `static` class members (methods and variables). When in object context and referencing a non-static member, always use `$this`. (e.g. `$this->create()`);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood what you want to say, all you have to do is change the code in the `create()` method to be similar to the `make()`, making `create()` a public method with the `make()` signature and removing the `make()` method from the class:

```php
public function create($table_array)  
{  
    foreach($table_array as $table) {
        $type = $table["type"];

        switch ($type)   
        {  
            case "credentials":  
                database::query('CREATE TABLE credentials(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, flname VARCHAR(60), email VARCHAR(32), pass VARCHAR(40), PRIMARY KEY(id))');  
                break;  
            case "booomark":  
                database::query('CREATE TABLE boomark(name VARCHAR(64), url VARCHAR(256), tag VARCHAR(256), id INT)');  
                break;  
            case "tweet":  
                database::query('CREATE TABLE tweet(time INT, fname VARCHAR(32), message VARCHAR(128), email VARCHAR(64))');  
                break;  
            default:  
                throw new Exception('Invalid Table Type');  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I think I got it. I've edited my answer to accept and array as input and looping though it. You can use your original structure, just updating the `make()` method as in this answer, calling the `create()` method as before, just to separate the logic. See if I really got it.